# Having trouble compiling yaml.swift for iOS (builds fine for OSX)

Tags: ios, macos, swift

So I have to import some YML files into my latest swift project, and I found this lovely library (https://github.com/behrang/yaml.swift) which seems to work beautifully. The problem is, it's an iOS project and by default yaml.swift compiles for OSX.

Not too big of a deal, I changed this line in the makefile

```
sdk = $$(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)
```

to this

```
sdk = $$(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphoneos)
```

As soon as I make this switch, I get all sorts of errors when I compile.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/mach/ndr.h:37:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/mach/ndr.h:37:
#include <libkern/OSByteOrder.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSByteOrder.h:45:10: error: 'libkern/machine/OSByteOrder.h' file not found
#include <libkern/machine/OSByteOrder.h>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/shims/shims.h:13:10: error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <stddef.h>        // for size_t
         ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftShims'
make: *** [build/libyaml.dylib] Error 1
```

That's the last few lines, but this goes back for a few thousand lines. Nothing that I can find appears to be related to the library I'm trying to compile. It almost seems as if it's a problem with the SDK. I've tried digging and seeing whether or not the library is dependent on OSX frameworks, but the only thing it imports is `Foundation`.

Any ideas what the error could be related to?

What I've come up with so far is, [SwiftShims](https://github.com/andelf/Defines-Swift/blob/master/SwiftShims.swift) is a swift module (NOT Objective-C as the error says). At the top of the SwiftShims.swift file, it appears to be importing some Darwin/C modules. Perhaps this is the issue? But SwiftShims isn't being imported in any of the swift files for this module. I'm really lost here, I'd appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: Have you tried using `iphonesimulator` as the SDK? It might be that you do not have the complete iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell the swift compiler to build for the x86 cpu from which your simulator is running. In the make file, you need to also add:

```
-target x86_64-apple-ios8.0
```

as one of the swiftc options under the libyml.dylib section.